# How does Java determine which Thread should proceed when using synchronized?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, queue

```
private static void WaitInQueue(Customer c)
{         
    synchronized(mutex){
       //Do some operation here.
    }              

}
```

I need to make threads wait before proceeding(only one at a time), however, it appears that synchronized is not using FIFO to determine which should proceed next.(It seems like LIFO) Why is this?

How can I ensure that the first thread to wait at synchronized will be the first one to aquire the lock next?

Comment: I guess scheduling of thread is being taken care by the underlying operating system.

Comment: Java does not try to order, it's essentially random.

Comment: use queue to ensure synchronization fairness

Comment: Even if you start two threads assuming their priorities are same, you can not tell which thread will execute first, its the operating system decides and based on the availability of the processor.

Comment: @zapl It is not essentially random and in reality may be quite non-random. The only point is that the JLS doesn't *specify* any order so the implementations have the freedom to use the most efficient strategy.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Right but I would argue that you must assume it is random because that's the strongest assumption you can make based on the specification.

Comment: @zapl No, it is much too strong an assumption. Threads may be chosen on a strict LIFO basis---far away from the "chosen at random" assumption, and fatally so.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik & zapl, you're both right. We cannot make assumptions as the specification is intentionally left blank, however you also cannot assume random in this case because it is likely LIFO and there are negative consequences of a LIFO order that you'd ignore if you assumed the order was random. For example (LIFO), during thread pile-up the "First In" may never get executed. So the answer is; we do not rely on any specific ordering but we also protect against harmful ordering. AKA "Healthy Paranoia" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a synchronized block makes no guarantees about fairness - any of the waiting threads may in theory be chosen to execute. if you really want a fair lock (fifo), switch to use the newer locking mechanisms introduced in java 5+.
see for example the [documentation for ReentrantLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html).
here's how you'd use a fair lock:

```
private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock(true); //fair lock
   // ...

   public void m() {
     lock.lock();  // block until condition holds
     try {
       // ... method body
     } finally {
       lock.unlock()
     }
   }
```

note, however, that this results in overall degraded performance and so is not recommended.
quoting from the documentation"

> The constructor for this class accepts an optional fairness parameter.
>   When set true, under contention, locks favor granting access to the
>   longest-waiting thread. Otherwise this lock does not guarantee any
>   particular access order. Programs using fair locks accessed by many
>   threads may display lower overall throughput (i.e., are slower; often
>   much slower) than those using the default setting

Comment: Not guaranteeing any particular order and choosing at random are quite different concepts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Semaphore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) class, with a fairness setting set to true and a count of 1. This guarantees FIFO order for threads, and is almost identical to having a synchronized block.

`ReentrantLock` also provides a fairness setting.

Answer (score 0):

**To answer "Why is this?":**  There's rarely any reason to use a specific order on a lock.  The threads hit the lock in random order and may as well leave it the same way.  The important thing from the JVM's viewpoint is to keep the cores busy working on your program's code.  Generally, if you care about what order your threads run in you need something a lot fancier than a lock or semaphore.

The only good exception I can think of is if your lock *always* has waiting threads, creating the real possibility that a thread that hits it might wait for many seconds, continually getting bumped to the back of the "queue", while an irate user fumes.  Then, FIFO makes a lot of sense.  But even here you might want to spend some time trying to speed up the synchronized block (or avoiding it completely) so most threads that hit it don't get blocked.

In summary, think long and hard about your design if you find yourself worrying about the order your threads run in.

Answer (score -1):

You should use Thread.join for wait before proceeding.
Just go through the following link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsw9f9ts(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: That's not a very good idea, and it would make the code unnecessarily complicated.